# JavaScript global variable is shown as undefined in Google Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm very much new to JavaScript. This question may be something very primitive. The posts that are suggested when I was typing this question didn't help me to resolve the issue.

I was following a tutorial and it uses Google Chrome console for exercises. It showed that the global and window objects tables could be printed on the console.

I tried and window was printed but not the **global** object. Why is this? Do I need to upgrade to a certain version of chrome/install other plugin to support global variables?

It says "Global is not defined"

[image]

Comment: "I was following a tutorial" — a link would be useful so that we could tell if this was an error in the tutorial or if you misunderstood something about it.

Comment: Thanks! It's a vedio tutorial https://www.udemy.com/programming-in-javascript. There is a section on "The global object"

Comment: Oh I went through it again. It asks me to run the browser in "incognito mode". I don't know what was that but it resolved the issue. Thanks for pointing me back to the tutorial again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the answer to the question.

The Chrome browser has to be in the "Incognito mode" to see the global object.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by global variables?
If you define a variable
"var x = 0"
Outside of any functions it's global and can be called anywhere.

Including in the console.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. it's not variable, it's global object.

Answer (score -1):

Have you perhaps run across a NodeJS tutorial where `global` is used to create a global variable outside of a module?

https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global

This is not valid in browser JavaScript, even though in NodeJS it is still JavaScript, the global stuff is a little different.